# How do I access data from Python files (.pkl, pickle)?

Tags: python, pickle

New here and figured this would be the perfect place to ask a quick question.

I've been struggling to access the data from this webpage: http://sidekick.epfl.ch/data

I need to access the data for my thesis, but the "example.py" file that is supposed to run and explain how to use the data simply doesn't. I've also never encountered ".pkl" files in the past which is making things harder.

I haven't had any problem with the npy files, but I'd love to get some help so I can run all the files and get a full picture of the data. If anyone knows how, could you please explain the procedure to me? I only have a basic understanding of the concepts.

Thank you all very much for your help,

Marc

Comment: Pickle files are simply a means of marshalling data, which can include object instances. Python has a `pickle` module which you should look into.

Answer (score 0):

You can load pickle files as follows. Don't forget to add `"rb"` to the `open` method, as you need to open the file in binary mode.

```
import pickle

with open(path, "rb") as f:
    content = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: It seems to help but unfortunately I'm still unable to make it work. I get the following error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 25: ordinal not in range(128).


Would you be able to break down the steps to fix this?

Thank you very much

Comment: You might wanna do your `open` call like `open(path, "rb", encoding="utf-8")` in that case.